# is this trie java program efficient?

Tags: java, data-structures, trie

is there any other efficient solution? 
do i have to replace the fixed sized array of objects?
how do you rate my program on scale of 1-10 based on time and space efficiency?
how can i make this program efficient? i want to use it to create a dictionary?
thanks in advance.

```
 public class Dict {
        boolean isWord;
        Dict obj[];
        Dict()
        {
            obj=new Dict[26];// as there are 26 alphabets in english
            isWord=false;
        }
        Dict insertWord(Dict Node,String str, int it) // insert a word in trie
        {
            if(it<str.length())
            {
            int Linkno=((int)(str.charAt(it)))-97; // 97 is the ascii value of 'a'.
            if(Node.obj[Linkno]==null)
            {
                Node.obj[Linkno]=new Dict();
            }
            insertWord(Node.obj[Linkno],str,it+1);
            }
            else
            {
                Node.isWord=true;
            }
            return Node;
        }
        void displayAll(Dict Node,String str) //display all the words stored in trie
        {
            for(int i=0;i<26;i++)
            {
                if(Node.obj[i]!=null)
                {
                    if(Node.obj[i].isWord==true)
                        System.out.println(str+((char)(i+97)));
                    displayAll(Node.obj[i],(str+((char)(i+97))));
                }
            }
        }
        public static void main(String ar[])
        {
            Dict root=new Dict();
            root.insertWord(root,"trasaction",0);
            root.insertWord(root,"transformation",0);
            root.insertWord(root,"transmission",0);
            root.insertWord(root,"trance",0);
            root.insertWord(root,"trap",0);
            root.displayAll(root,"");
        }
    }
```

Comment: If you code works, you need to post this question at http://codereview.stackexchange.com/ not here :)

Comment: Your code has magic numbers like 26 and 97 with no comments whatsoever. If I were your teacher/boss/whatever, I wouldn't bother trying to read it under those circumstances.

Comment: I agree with @dfeuer. In most cases, it's more important to make your code readable and easy to maintain, than efficient...

Comment: What is your expectation for efficiency? How fast should it be or how do measure performance?

Comment: What happens if I insert a word with a capital letter, or use a spelling like "manœver"? How will you prevent your program from crashing, or is crashing okay in those cases?

Comment: dfeuer i can handle that exception but i want to know whether this is a efficient way to implement trie or is there any other efficient way. thanks

Comment: @JordiCastilla This is very wrong in general, but this questions seems to be a good candidate for CR, indeed.